# Sitecore 9.2 (002893) equivalent DLLs for Sitecore 8.1 rev. 151207

Tags: sitecore, sitecore8.1, sitecore9

I was using a sitecore 8.1 151207 instance and Now I'm upgrading the solution to a 9.2 002893

In my 8.1 solution I have called following methods

```
 WorkflowCounters.ActionsExecuted.IncrementBy(int amount)
 Factory.GetMessage(Item item)
```

I've removed 8.1 dlls and added 9.2 dlls. Now some of the methods are not working due to unavailability of the dll references or due to some other issue(may be they have changed the method name, class name etc)

Here are the name spaces of those classes.

```
 WorkflowCounters >> Sitecore.Diagnostics.PerformanceCounters
 Factory >> Sitecore.Modules.EmailCampaign
```

Can someone help me by mentioning what the new method/class is to be used or the namespace to be used?

Answer (score 1):

1)
The Sitecore.Diagnostics.PerformanceCounters.WorkflowCounters.ActionsExecuted.IncrementBy namespace is now:

> Sitecore.Diagnostics.PerformanceCounters.DataCount.WorkflowActionsExecuted.IncrementBy

Inside Sitecore.Kernel

2)
In Sitecore 8.1 there was an option module, Email Experience Manager. In Sitecore 9.2 this module is part of the core product. So this is why EmailCampaign related namespaces are changed. Also some things are changed in the architecture. The introduction of service bus implementation, The Sitecore Message bus runs on Rebus.

Looks like you try to use some functionality replaced by the new service bus. so it is not just change a namespace, I suppose you want to send an EXM email. The new way is documented on https://doc.sitecore.com see
https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/exm/92/email-experience-manager/en/sending-email-campaigns-programmatically.html